# Cardinal equality: $\;\left|\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\right|=\left|\{0,1,2,3\}^{\Bbb N}\right|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to prove the above equality without Cantor-Bernstein Theorem or cardinals arithmetic (i.e., a bijection must be found).

I know that for example $\;S\to 1_S=\;$ the indicator function, gives a bijection $\;P(\Bbb N)\to \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\;$ , so if I can find a bijection $\;P(\Bbb N)\to\{01,2,3\}^{\Bbb N}\;$ then I can compose these two and that's all. Yet this last one is making problems to me, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$ is equipotent to $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Use even and odd coordinates.

Comment: Thank you Henno, yet I still can't see your point as the left set is $\;\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\;$ and not the cartesian product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: You can interpret a binary sequence as a sequence base four by grouping it into pairs of digits.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. Let me see if I get your point: every pair in the sequence will be translated to basis four say by a law like $$(0,0)\to 0\;,\;\;(0,1)\to 1\;,\;\;(1,0)\to 2\;,\;\;(1,1)\to3\;?$$ Thus, we'd get for instance $$(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,...)\to (1,3,3,0,2,2,0,2,...)\;\;?$$

Comment: Yes, it looks so beautiful that it's hard for me to convince me it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joanpemo: You’re very welcome. Yes, that’s exactly what I was suggesting.