# Cardinal Numbers and powers related to them

Tags: number-theory, cardinals

Cardinal numbers are used to express sizes of sets.

It $c$ is a cardinal number then $2^c$ is also a cardinal number which represents size of the set of all subsets of a set whose cardinality is $c$.

**Question:** What $3^c,4^c,\cdots$ represent? Are that all equal to $2^c$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if $a$ and $b$ are two cardinal numbers, then we define $a^b$ to be the cardinality of the set of all functions from $b$ to $a$. In particular, you can show that $2^A$ is the cardinality of the power set of $A$. You can think of $4^A$ as the cardinality of the power set of the disjoint union $A \sqcup A$.

---

In fact, if $c$ is any infinite cardinal, then we have $3^c=4^c=...=2^c$.

Indeed, we can show that $2^c=5^c$, for instance. Clearly, $2^c ≤ 5^c$ holds. On the other hand, you have $5 ≤ 2^c$, and since $c$ is [infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577022) : $c^2=c$. Therefore, $$5^c ≤ (2^c)^c = 2^{c^2}=2^c.$$ By [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), we conclude that $2^c=5^c$.

Of course, if $c$ is a finite cardinal with $c \neq \varnothing$, then $2^c=k^c \implies k=2$.

Comment: The last comment on finite cardinals is not true for $c = \emptyset$, because $2^\emptyset = k^\emptyset$ for any $k$.

Comment: @Thorsten : yes, I wasn't precise enough. I fixed it.

Comment: Of course the OP asked what the notations $3^c$, etc, represented. You really can't prove that $3^c=2^c$ before _defining_ $3^c$...

Answer (score 1):

Detail: "$c$" is a bad letter to use for a general cardinal, because $c$ is standard notation for a specific cardinal, namely the cardinality of the reals.

If $\kappa$ and $\mu$ are cardinals then $\mu^\kappa$ represents the cardinality of the set of all mappings from a set of size $\kappa$ to a set of size $\mu$. If $\kappa$ is infinite and $\mu\ge2$ is finite then it turns out that $\mu^\kappa=2^\kappa$.

Comment: I'd add: the cardinality of the set of subsets is not **by definition** $2^c$ (to use the questioner's notation), and to force it to have this meaning causes confusion. It being $2^c$ is more like a *theorem*, stemming from the fact that 2 is the cardinality of the set {Yes,No}. Each subset or the original set corresponds to $c$ Yes/No answers to the question "Is this particular item in this particular subset?".