# Equinumerosity from one set of functions to another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove equinumerosity of the following using the Schröder–Bernstein theorem:

$\{0, 1, 2, 3\}^\Bbb N ∼\{0, 1\}^\Bbb N$

And I'm having some trouble with finding an injective function $\Rightarrow$ and could use some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can actually get a bijection as easily as you can a pair of injections: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636549/cardinal-equality-left-0-1-bbb-n-right-left-0-1-2-3-bbb-n-r) and its answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Given a sequence of $0$s, $1$s, $2$s and $3$s, write each of the entries in the sequence as binary expressions with two digits, i.e. as $00$, $01$, $10$ or $11$, and then just insert commas to turn it into a sequences of $0$s and $1$s.

All you need to do now is translate this intuition into the definition of a function, and prove that this function is injective. (In fact,  it's bijective, eliminating the need for Schröder-Bernstein altogether.)